# Suppose we have $T$ is onto and $Span(v_1,\ldots,v_n) = V$. Prove that$ Span(T(v_1),\ldots,T(v_n)) = W$.

Tags: linear-algebra

> Suppose $T:V \to W$ is a surjective linear transformation and let $\{v_1,v_2,\cdots,v_n\}$ is a basis of $V$.  How do I show that $$\text{Span} (T(v_1),...,T(v_n)) = W \;?$$

I have an idea of how to show $\text{Span}(T(v_1),...,T(v_n))$ is a subspace of W, but I am unsure how to show that W is a subspace of $\text{Span}(T(v_1),...,T(v_n))$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $w \in W$. Then $w=T(v)$ for some $v \in V$. Since $\{v_i\}$ is a basis for $V$,  $$v=\sum_{i=1}^n \alpha_iv_i$$ Linearity of $T$ implies $$w=T(v)=\sum_{i=1}^n \alpha_iT(v_i) \in \text{span}(T(v_i)) $$ so $W \subset \text{span}(T(v_i))$

Answer (score 0):

Consider a linear map $T:V\to W$ and let $v_1,\dotsc,v_n\in V$. Note that $\operatorname{Span}\{v_1,\dotsc, v_n\}$ is a subspace of $V$. Furthermore, the image of $\operatorname{Span}\{v_1,\dotsc,v_n\}$ under $T$ is 
$$
T(\operatorname{Span}\{v_1,\dotsc, v_n\})=\operatorname{Span}\{T(v_1), \dotsc, T(v_n)\}\tag{$\ast$}
$$
Now, if $T$ is onto and $\operatorname{Span}\{v_1,\dotsc, v_n\}=V$, we have
$$
\operatorname{Span}\{T(v_1), \dotsc, T(v_n)\}
= T(\operatorname{Span}\{v_1,\dotsc, v_n\})
= T(V)
= W
$$
This proves the result, assuming (1) is true. Can you prove ($\ast$)?